# Img tags inside an Anchor in an Flash/AS3 HTMLtextfield with embedFonts = true, and a css file for styles behaves unexpected? Any solution?

Tags: actionscript-3, image, fonts, anchor, gaia

when the embedFonts is removed, it works perfectly as expect. Otherwise when an image is clicked, it selects the whole text around it.

Alternatively can anyone suggest a method to style dynamic textfields instead of using html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to have bring the same effect without using the anchor tag. Apparently there's a bug in using Anchor tag with images. Anyway here's what I did to overcome this.

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
private function init():void {

     //....
     var txt:String = "Curabitur dolor eros, gravida et.<p class='defStyle'><img src='003.jpg' id='0002'><br><br><br><br><br>Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio.</p>";
     testtext.htmlText=txt;

     var myPattern:RegExp =/<img[^>]+ids*=s*['"]([A-Za-z0-9]+)['"][^>]*\s*>/igmxs;  
     var result:Object = myPattern.exec(txt);

     while (result != null) {
          var id = result[1];
          trace(id);
          var image:DisplayObject = testtext.getImageReference(id);
          image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imgClick);
          image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
          image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
          result = myPattern.exec(txt);
      }

     ...//more

}

function imgClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
     trace('hello '+e.target.name);
}
function mouseOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
     Mouse.cursor='button';
}
function mouseOutHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
     Mouse.cursor='auto';
}
```